# How to send soap data with apache cxf to an external service

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, jboss6.x

I am very new to jboss fuse and i am using apache cxf for my restful webservices. I have a fuse projects that listens to my csv file directory for data and uses my POJO java class to process it. How can i send this data to an external webservice with in SOAP format.

my blueprint file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

  <bean id="bindyDataformat" class="org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat">
    <argument value="org.csvdemo.websocketdemo.Product" />
  </bean>

  <camelContext trace="false" id="blueprintContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <route>
    <from uri="file://csv/?noop=true&amp;delete=true"/>
    <split>
      <tokenize token="\n"></tokenize>
      <unmarshal ref="bindyDataformat"/>
      <log message="${body}"/>
    </split>
  </route>
</camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post seems like it has a few things missing such as your bindyDataFormat being created for example.  You need a bit of initial setup with cxf as it is a very large framework.  I would recommend going through this tutorial: http://camel.apache.org/cxf-example.html